# Put an existing file to data\data\app_name\files during .apk installaion

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I need to work with a file,that should be at data\data\app_name\files\ . That is now an SQL Database, so solution with SQLiteOpenHelper isn't ok for me. Also, I copyied that file to app_name\app\assets in my profect folder - that didn't work.
How to add that file to installation .apk, to put it in data\data\app_name\files during the installation?

Comment: Can't it be generated via code when the user runs the app the first time?

Comment: No. Well, I can put an information to source code and create a file on intallation with that info, but that info is 9 Mb of text, and I think there are more correct and elegant way,. Nevertheless, I won't find the solution - I'll act exactly that way.

Answer (score 0):

Save your file in `\res\raw` within your project.

Then, you can access that file using:

```
InputStream databaseInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);
```

Make sure that the resource files are included correctly when generating the apk.